# How to find the shortest word on a text file

Tags: shell

So i have all these words in a text file:

```
dfasdfasdf
adsgad
fghjast
hdasfh
adfhadfn
```

And i have to display the number of chars of the smallest word without using the 'awk' and 'sed' commands...
I have tried all variants of wc but it works with the full text file and not only line per line.

Edit: I apologize for not giving more details on the subject. I am learning Shell basics and have not started programming on Linux yet. The point on this exercise that i Have is to show in the screen how many characters that the shortest word has. To this point I have only learned the commands tr, cp, cut, sort, head, tail, grep, find,wc... So I can't use awk/sed/any other command that I have learned on the internet or programming on this...

Comment: What do you mean by smallest? The shortest? Can you use `sort`?

Comment: Yes, the shortest one. I have used sort but it only sorts me the words by alphabetical order.

Comment: `mapfile -t arr < yourtextfile; for f in "${arr[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "${#f}"; done | sort -n |head -n1`  or using the `read` as follows: `while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "${#line}"; done < fff | sort -n | head -n1`

Comment: If you've been given arbitrary restrictions by some external entity, perhaps you can explain what other methods you've been given to learn about so that we can meaningfully extend them.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not giving more details on the subject. I am learning Shell basics and have not started programming on Linux yet. The point on this exercise that i Have is to show in the screen how many characters that the shortest word has. To this point I have only learned the commands tr, cp, cut, sort, head, tail, grep, find,wc... So I can't use awk or programming on this...

Answer (score 3):

Using parameter expansion, you can get the length of a variable contents:

```
${#variable}
```

Just read the file line by line and remember the shortest word:

```
while read word ; do
    : ${shortest:=$word}  # Initialize $shortest if not set.
    if [ ${#word} -lt ${#shortest} ] ; then
        shortest=$word
    fi
done < file.txt
echo "$shortest"
```